# "Error (frameset): Wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p, nil" How to debug it?

Tags: init-file, debugging, frames, error

Such a message in the "Warnings" window. "Frameset" I think refers to the .emacs.desktop file. I got this message when Emacs in daemon mode restored the desktop. There is no such message when running the GUI Emacs.

What could be wrong? How to debug it?

```
(defun herman/try-read-desktop ()
    (when (desktop-save-mode t)
          ; your init code here
          (message "Inside server-after-make-frame-hook")
          ;; (setq desktop-save-mode t)
          (desktop-read)
      ))

(add-hook 'server-after-make-frame-hook 'herman/try-read-desktop)
```

Comment: `(setq toggle-debug-on-error t)` first, and then add the backtrace to your question.

Comment: It looks like the error will be coming from `(desktop-read)` though, so you can also test just calling that directly.

Comment: Apologies; that should be `(setq debug-on-error t)`.  I'd written `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` initially but realised you needed it set before you could interact with Emacs, and I messed up the edit.

Comment: You can also do `M-x debug-on-entry desktop-read`, if you want to go through it carefully.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18612742/emacs-desktop-save-mode-error#comment47963002_26546872

`(setq desktop-restore-forces-onscreen nil)`

Comment: thanks. I needed that. I hadn't found the linked source.